# Errors in SQL Syntax

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to run MySQL query through a python script and keep getting an error in my SQL syntax, from I can see the query is set up correctly. Could someone please give me a second set of eyes on this?

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    connect = conn.cursor()
    query = u'INSERT INTO page_load_times (self, object_id, page_header, elapsed_time, date_run) ' \
            'VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, {})'.format(self, self.object_id, self.page_header, t.interval, timestamp)
    connect.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

The error I am getting is below:

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '13:56:17.491000)' at line 1
```

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Guessing oen of those is a string and it's nto quoted in your query...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pass query parameters via string formatting.

Let the mysql client do the job by passing parameters into the query in the second argument to `execute()`. Aside from not having problems with quotes and data type conversions, you would avoid sql injection risks:

```
query = """INSERT INTO 
               page_load_times 
               (self, object_id, page_header, elapsed_time, date_run)
           VALUES 
               (%(self)s, %(object_id)s, %(page_header)s, %(interval)s, %(timestamp)s)"""
params = {'self': self, 
          'object_id': self.object_id, 
          'page_header': self.page_header, 
          'interval': t.interval, 
          'timestamp': timestamp}

connect.execute(query, params)
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it may work, as soon as I figure out a problem with someone else's code.